# Localhost refused to connect express

Tags: node.js, express

The following code works fine on `http://localhost:5000/`

```
const http = require('http')


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.end('Home Page')
  }
})

server.listen(5000)
```

However when I try the code below

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Home Page')
})

app.listen((5000, () => {
  console.log('listening to port 5000')
}))
```

`listening to port 5000` is console logged, but I get a `This site can’t be reached` message when I visit `http://localhost:5000/` as localhost refuses to connect. I made sure I did `npm install` to get `express` from my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "02-express-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Why is node working but express is not?

Comment: I think you just have a pair of parentheses too much in the listen call. So it only passes 1 argument, the callback, and never the port. Like `var x = (5000,"something")` would just eval to "something"

Comment: @TobiasK. That was the answer, my silly mistake. If you answer the question, would gladly give the +10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a pair of parentheses too much in the listen call. So it only passes 1 argument, the callback, and never the port. Like `var x = (5000,"something")` would just eval to "something".

Use:

```
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('listening to port 5000')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code:
CONVERT THIS:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Home Page')
})

app.listen((5000, () => {
  console.log('listening to port 5000')
}))
```

TO:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Home Page')
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('listening to port 5000')
})
```

The error is in the app.listen

Have a Good Day!